# Why Angular Karma Test (npm test) can not start Google Chrome and ended up with error code 8?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Enviroment**

- Windows 10
- Angular 4
- Karma 1.7.0

I am totaly new to this topic and i try to run just a simple test. But I reach all the time the following error message:

```
01 08 2017 09:21:59.859:DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-53868757 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-de
vice-discovery-notifications http://localhost:9876/?id=53868757
01 08 2017 09:22:02.925:DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 8
01 08 2017 09:22:02.925:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
[10036:6688:0801/092200:ERROR:external_registry_loader_win.cc(89)] Missing value path for key Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\flliilndjeohchalpbbcdekjklbdgfkk.
[10036:6688:0801/092200:ERROR:external_registry_loader_win.cc(89)] Missing value path for key Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl.
[10036:6688:0801/092200:ERROR:external_registry_loader_win.cc(89)] Missing value path for key Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\lmjegmlicamnimmfhcmpkclmigmmcbeh.
```

If i try to start the browser itselfe (`C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`) the browser starts.

**Additional Information**

- Server is online
- Testcases exist
- npm install is done
- command  `npm test` runs as Administrator (Powershell)

I reach an Information in an error alert with the following information, (translated)

> An administrator has installed Google Chrome on this system. It is
>   available to all users. Installing Google Chrome on your system level
>   now replaces your installation at the user level.

[image]

If I click on "ok" nothing happen and the programm try to start Chrome again, same in case of ding nothing. It ended up with: `01 08 2017 10:15:46.782:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.`

I use the latest Google Chrom version.

[image]

** Karma Config File **

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-tap'),
      require('karma-sourcemap-loader'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 360000,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

What could be the problem? 
How to set the Missing value path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now it works. It looks like that PowerShell does not know my Chrome-Path.
I set the variable, an now it works very fine.

```
 $Env:CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) even if [it is your own post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).